# Pyramid of doom Grape endpoints

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, api

I'm creating an API endpoint to create and delete associations, essential creating and deleting records of a join model.

The code below doesn't seem idiomatic or pragmatic at all. What's the best way to create 2 endpoints, POST and DELETE for the same route?

```
module API
  module V1
    class UserActivities < Grape::API
      include API::V1::Defaults

      format :json

      namespace :users do

        route_param :user_id do
          resource :activities do
            desc 'Create User + Activity associations'
            route_param :activity_id do
              post do
                #pyramid of doom
              end
            end
          end

          resource :activities do
            desc 'Delete User + Activity associations'
            route_param :activity_id do
              delete do
                #pyramid of doom
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This generates the following routes:

```
   POST  |  /api/:version/users/:user_id/activities/:activity_id(.:format)  |  v1  |  Create User + Activity associations
 DELETE  |  /api/:version/users/:user_id/activities/:activity_id(.:format)  |  v1  |  Delete User + Activity associations
```

But is there a better way to do this using Grape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to define the whole flow per route, this still leads you to the pyramid of hell.

```
  namespace :users do
    route_param :user_id do
      resource :activities do
        desc 'Create User + Activity associations'
        route_param :activity_id do
          post do
            #pyramid of doom
          end

          delete do
            #pyramid of doom
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

However, you can register parts of the route in different files

```
namespace :users do
  register UserActivities
end
```

Then, within user_activities.rb you can add the rest of the code